# How to get imageUrl from firebase storage and store in firebase database in Xcode 10 swift 4.2

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, xcode10, swift4.2

Here is the code that I'm using

```
@objc func handleSignUp() {
        guard let email = emailTextField.text, email.characters.count > 0 else { return }
        guard let username = usernameTextField.text, username.characters.count > 0 else { return }
        guard let password = passwordTextField.text, password.characters.count > 0 else { return }

    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in
         if let err = error {
            print("Failed to create user:", err)
            return
        }
        print("Successfully created user:", user?.user.uid)
        //            guard let image = self.plusPhotoButton.imageView?.image else { return }
        //            guard let uploadData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.3) else { return }
        guard let uploadData = self.plusPhotoButton.imageView?.image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.3) else{return}

        let filename = NSUUID().uuidString
        Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_images").child(filename).putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, err) in
             if let err = err {
                print("Failed to upload profile image:", err)
                return
            }
//this code isn't correct for swift4.2
//guard let profileImageUrl = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString else    { return } 


            func getDownloadURL(from path: String, completion: @escaping (URL?, Error?) -> Void) {
                let storageReference = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://instagramfirebase-60be5.appspot.com")

                let storageRef = storageReference.child(path).downloadURL(completion: completion)
            }
            print("Successfully uploaded profile image")//,profileImageUrl

            guard let uid = user?.user.uid else { return }
            let dictionaryValues = ["username": username] as [String : Any]//, "profileImageUrl": profileImageUrl
            let values = [uid: dictionaryValues]

            Database.database().reference().child("users").updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in

                if let err = err {
                    print("Failed to save user info into db:", err)
                    return
                }

                print("Successfully saved user info to db")
            })
        })
    })
}
```

Snapshots are as followed :

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am confused about how to get  the `imageUrl` from firebase storage and store it in firebase database in Xcode 10 swift 4.2

Please help, Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the download url easily by using the following code inside the closure of your image-upload:

```
storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
    if let err = error{
       // error happened - implement code to handle it
       print(err)
    } else {
       // no error happened; so just continue with your code
       print(url?.absoluteString) // this is the actual download url - the absolute string
    }
```

Please note: Don't store the downloadURL on its own as Firebase can change tokens of the downloadURL, I'd suggest to always grab a hold of the full storage path.

I hope I was able to help.